# Comments and questions with "invalid" Unicode characters fail badly

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I was trying to comment on [a question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623877/php-domxpath-query-class-name-that-contains-emoji) with this text:

> Have you tried `"//[@class='&#x1F41D;ap0']"`? Not sure where you got D83D, which is xxxx.

Where xxxx is the Unicode character U+D83D.

Whenever I clicked the comment button, I got sent to this URL:

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55623877/php-domxpath-query-class-name-that-contains-emoji?comment=Have+you+tried+%60%22%2F%2F%5B%40class%3D%27%26%23x1F41D%3Bap0%27%5D%22%60%3F+Not+sure+where+you+got+D83D%2C+which+is+%EF%BF%BD.
```

With this error in the console:

```
URIError: malformed URI sequence jquery.min.js:4:25041
    jQuery 4
        e
        dc
        param
        ajax
    beat https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=fc0fd2b56f16:3
    a https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/wmd.en.js?v=fc0fd2b56f16:3
    e https://meta.stackoverflow.com/content/Js/tagsuggestions.en.js?v=78eee7c19ab2:1
    jQuery 2
        dispatch
        handle
```

The comment was not posted. The same error occurred when trying to post this question with the character in the body, though I did not get sent to a different URL. [Looking into this](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/d83d/index.htm) it seems like it may not be a valid character (at least on its own) but a more graceful failure is to be expected!

To help reproduce this bug you can run the following to display the invalid character for copying:

```js
prompt('Copy this:', '\uD83D');
```

Comment: _“Looking into this it seems like it may not be a valid character”_ — yes, it’s a high surrogate code point, which only works in conjunction with a low surrogate code point. These are used in UTF-16 encoding. This is also where U+D83D came from. The question seems to be about U+1F41D which can be represented as U+D83D and U+DC1D in UTF-16. It seems, these were split apart somehow.

Answer (score 14):

That's an interesting find. (edit: So interesting [that I decided it was worth cross-posting to Stack Overflow itself](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55660960/1114).) As you suggested, those "invalid" characters aren't actually defined as characters in Unicode. The Unicode code points from `\uD800` to `\uDFFF` are reserved so that the UCS-2 and UTF-16 text encodings can use pairs of them to identify other valid Unicode character code points that would otherwise be out-of-range for those encodings. For all other encodings, these code points cannot be used, and for UTF-16, the code points are only allowed to occur in valid pairs that can be mapped to valid character code points when converting to another encoding.

Unfortunately, JavaScript chose UCS-2 before UTF-16 was standardized, and UCS-2 *does* allow you to include surrogate characters on their own, without being paired to produce a valid code point. Because JavaScript allows it, browsers are still able to accept it as input. This is a complication, but in most cases it doesn't actually get in users' way like you're experiencing. For example, if I disable JavaScript, I am then able to submit a post containing an unpaired surrogate. How does that work?

The browser takes a common approach to encoding incompatibilities: any characters that can't be translated to the target encoding are replaced by `�` the Unicode replacement character. Because the page's encoding is set to UTF-8 (by the `Content-Type` header), the browser automatically performs this replacement when encoding the form data for submission. However, if JavaScript is enabled, the request is sent using jQuery's "AJAX" utilities instead of the standard browser form submission mechanism. jQuery doesn't have any such logic, and nor does the built-in `encodeURIComponent` function that it calls when encoding form data: it just throws an error.

```javascript
encodeURIComponent('\uD83D') // URIError: malformed URI sequence
```

This is specified in [Section 18.2.6.1.1: Runtime Semantics: `Encode`](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-encode) of ECMAScript 6.

To reproduce the standard browser form behaviour in JavaScript, one would replace any instances where a "high surrogate" in the range `\uD800` to `\uDBFF` occurs without being followed by a "low surrogate" in the range `\uDC00` to `\uDFFF`, or vice-versa. That might look something like this:

```javascript
const replaceUnpairedSurrogates = s => s
  .replace(/[\uD800-\uDBFF]+([^\uDC00-\uDFFF]|$)/g, '�$1')
  .replace(/(^|[^\uD800-\uDBFF])[\uDC00-\uDFFF]+/g, '$1�');

replaceUnpairedSurrogates("hello world!"); // "hello world!"
replaceUnpairedSurrogates("\uD83D\uD83D\uD83D-\uD83D"); "���-�"
replaceUnpairedSurrogates(""); // ""
```

Comment: Sorry, but... what do you mean��������������������������������������������������������������� I am in trouble, please explain. Thanks in advance. :P

Comment: Shows up for me as a string of U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.

Comment: @miken32 I think I've figured out what's going on. Updated answer.

Comment: I'm tempted to migrate the question to normal SO now...

Comment: @jpmc26 Then, you may have some difficulty making a MCVE because you don't have the source code of SE... (this one is client side code so it may be easier, I don't know)

Comment: @user202729 If I'm reading correctly, it's a client side issue in JS... meaning you don't need a server to reproduce.

Comment: @user202729 MVCE's aren't strictly necessary, and this question includes an error message and enough context to more-or-less identify the problem. It might be okay, but users can't vote to migrate away from meta, so it's probably a moot discussion.

Comment: Not to mention I posted it here because it's a bug in SO's text handling...